# Integrating Viewcomponent with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How can [viewcomponent](https://viewcomponent.org) tests be integrated with rspec? i can't find any documentation online regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

ViewComponent can indeed be integrated with rspec and is quite easy.
After you add the gem([Getting Started](https://viewcomponent.org/guide/getting-started.html#installation)), you have to add a few lines to your project's /spec/rails_helper.rb.
According to the documentation these additions are

rails_helper.rb

```
require "view_component/test_helpers"
require "capybara/rspec"
```

outside(**before**) the Rspec.configure block and the following **inside** the Rspec.configure block

```
  config.include ViewComponent::TestHelpers, type: :component
  config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, type: :component
```

Please refer to the documentation for up-to-date & additional configurations https://viewcomponent.org/guide/testing.html